# Is it best to use "get" as a prefix for getters?

Tags: readability, clean-code

if I had a boolean (property) `shouldAutoLogin` is it better to name the getter `getShouldAutoLogin` or just `shouldAutoLogin` so that it reads more like English?

ex :

```
if(shouldAutoLogin){
    ...
}
```

or

```
if(getShouldAutoLogin){
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is the a property named 'shouldAutoLogin'? Reflection in some languages (for example, jsp frameworks) expect that `${foo.something}` be translated into `foo.getSomething()` behind the scenes.

Comment: That seems to be the norm. For boolean values however it's also common to use `isFoo()` instead of `getFoo()`. In your example that would be `isAutoLogin()`

Comment: If you want to access any of those classes from a jsp, you pretty much have to.

Comment: @jmoreno while I (and others) have mentioned Java, it isn't clear that the OP is talking of it (if anything, given the choice of expressions inside of `if()` it is unlikely that it is Java.

Comment: yes, the question is not language specific, I was just interested in what other developers use as general guidelines

Comment: @MikeBryant Naming conventions are language specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The naming convention for getters are normally,

`getAutoLogin()` if getting some string or object.

`isAutoLogin()` for boolean.

Comment: This is naming convention for **java** which is part of [JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans). For c# you declare the property names without any prefix like get/set/is.

Comment: @k3b Thanks for the info. I am a Java Developer. :) But its good to know about C# convention too. Thanks

Comment: This question is about getters/setters, not properties. I thought getters and setters in C# usually start by get* or set* too (see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16718772/is-the-method-naming-for-property-getters-setters-standardized-in-il).

Comment: @sergut: True, but if the getter/setter methods are fast and idempotent, one would normally favor properties over getter and setter methods.  If they are not idempotent, get and set prefixes are probably misleading.  If they are not fast, get and set prefixes should probably be replaced with prefixes which make it more obvious that there are costs (e.g, use "calculateFrob" instead of "getFrob").

Comment: @Brian I was looking for some more clarification. The way I saw getters and setter were ONLY to get the private data and set the data. In the previous comment when you gave an example of calculateFrob(), that would be more like an operation/calculation to be done on the private data. That calculation can also be temporary and we might not need to set the private data. I hope you getting, the point I am trying to make here.

Comment: If we have an application with many private data, then remembering every property for those private data will be little difficult, since every private data might have its own unique property. So the way I see it was, do the operations/calculations set the data and get the data. It will be a lot easy as we will be sure that getXXX(), getYYY(), getZZZ() will exist for all the private data. Please let me know, if I am missing anything.

Comment: @JNL: I think I get your point, but in C# this is usually moot, per k3b's point.  If you had a private field "frob", you would probably have a property named "Frob," not a method named "getFrob".  In the case of properties with no intelligence, C# doesn't even require you to declare a backing field at all (e.g., `public string Frob {get;private set;}` creates a public getter for Frob and a private setter for Frob.  As an implementation detail, it also creates backing field, but your code will never see or talk to this field directly.

Comment: Tx @Brian Sounds good and interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Traditionally, getters are prefixed with `get` or `is` for the value.  This is often mentioned in java style guides.  For example [Java Programming Style Guide](http://www.cwu.edu/~gellenbe/javastyle/method.html) (this is just one example).

The convention for such method names is occasionally enforced in tools that use reflection or expect certain styles of code.  For example, again in Java (though JSP's Expression Language), `${foo.bar}` will be translated into the call `foo.getBar()` when the jsp is compiled.  The `getValue()` is enforced in this way so that it becomes more than just a convention.

As mentioned, the above examples are from Java.  This is a convention for *Java*.  Other languages have other conventions that should be looked at and likely followed too.  Some languages use properties (and can do other neat things with them like copy on request or read only).

Look into the style guides for your particular language choice.  It is probably a good idea to follow them when possible so that other coders, when reading your code, will more quickly be able to get into the code without trying to figure out your personal style.

Answer (score 2):

Naming a method in a cleverly readable way has advantages. Naming methods so that their intent and nature is easy to derive from the name ("getters have prefix `get`, boolean predicates, `is`") has advantages, too.

It's up to you to strike a balance, but in a large project benefits of consistency usually outweigh those of accidental cleverness.

Renaming a method to make the name both readable and convention-conformant is a nice daily exercise. In your particular case I'd consider something like `isAutoLoginEnabled` or `getAutoLoginFlag`.

OTOH you you have a bunch of conceptually similar methods that all can follow the pattern of `shouldDoSomething`, your original name can be fine, too.

Comment: I do like the added "Enabled" to the getter, it significantly improves the readability I find

Answer (score 1):

I always find that code should be as human readable as possible. It helps to clearly define the intentions of the code.
In your case think about what both the positive and negative uses of your boolean and how it would impact readability and the intentions of your logic would be.

```
if(!shouldAutoLogin)
{
     ....
}
```

versus

```
if(!getShouldAutoLogin)
{
    ....
}
```

Which gives a clearer meaning to the intention of what the code is trying to do?

As others have suggested, I would even rename the variable to

```
isShouldAutoLogin
```

or similar

Answer (score 0):

I tend to write `getAutoLogin` when I want the method to `return` a data type, like an `int` or a `String`. However, if I want to check if it's `true` or `false` (`boolean`), I simply swap the `get` to an `is` like this: `getAutoLogin` > `isAutoLogin`. I believe there is a naming convention for every language.